# PHP login script cookies reappear on every page, how to log out permanently?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I am trying to create a simple login logout system in PHP. This is being tested using WAMP and opened in chrome web browser.

The problem I face is while I seem to be able to create the session and the cookie okay, and even delete the cookie in logout script, any page visited from the same domain after the logout script is run automatically regenerates both cookies. This seems really strange as most other answers I have seen face the opposite issue of cookies dying.

I feel this may be an issue with the browser remembering, as if I delete the cookies from chrome, refreshing does not recreate the cookies, but am not sure how to mitigate this behaviour. As it stands this would mean users cannot truly log out of the system.

As an aside I appreciate this is not secured and md5 is not a suitable password solution, but am just looking to create simple functionality before adding these in.

login.php:

```
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');// connects to DB
// check database username and password.
if (isset($_POST['username']) & !empty($_POST)){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    // query login details to database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `database1` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // if logged in tell them.
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $errors[] = "</strong> already logged in, please logout to switch user";
    } 

    //only if username and password correct test other factors
    if($count == 1){

        // create new cookie with data //look up sql
        $cookie_name = 'Cookie';
        setcookie($cookie_name, test, 0, "/", ""); 
        // create session
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $smsg =  "user is logged in.";
        location.href = "memberpage.html";

    } else{ 
         $errors[] = "invalid username or password";
    }

}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
      <?php if(isset($smsg)&& !empty($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
            <?php if(isset($errors)){ 
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
      ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $error; ?> </div>
      <?php } }  ?>

      <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Log in</h2>
        <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($username) & !empty($username)){ echo $username; } ?>" required>
    </div>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="register.php">Register</a>
      </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
$cookie_name = 'Cookie';
setcookie( $cookie_name , '' , time() - 3600);
session_destroy();
if (!isset($_cookie[$cookie_name])){
//  header('location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Try and include the same parameters: `setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600, '/', ''); `

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. The cookies are successfully deleted on the logout page, but simply visiting another domain on the site, for example the login page, and they reappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), you need to also destroy the session ID cookie:

> In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

```
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600, '/', '');
```

Comment: This gave me the basis to delete the right cookie and it seems to persist. Thank you. -- accepted answer